# trying gitlab ci running flake8 returns error: pipenv run flake8

Tags: python, gitlab

trying out gitlab ci integration, and running into this problem while trying to run flake8 check

ci config

```
image: "python:3.9"

before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv install

stages:
  - Static Analysis

flake8:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
    - pipenv run flake8 --max-line-length=120 sample/*.py
```

```
$ pipenv run flake8 --max-line-length=120 sample/*.py
Error: the command flake8 could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts].
```

Comment: You'll have to install `flake8`.

Comment: but pipenv install shall install flake8, right ?

Comment: Only if configured to do so.

Comment: @KlausD. can u elaborate more, how to configure it to do so

Comment: Show us your `Pipfile`!

Comment: @KlausD. thanks got it resolved

Answer (score 0):

resolved by using

```
pipenv install --deploy --dev
```

final

```
image: "python:3.9"

before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv install --deploy --dev

stages:
  - Static Analysis

flake8:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
    - pipenv run flake8 --max-line-length=120 sample/*.py
```